# When can we apply Lebesgue Dominated theorem on increasing sequence of compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $A$ be a open and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose we have an increasing sequence of compact sets $\{B_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$ such that $A = \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n$. My question when can we say that

$\int_A f(x)dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{B_n}f(x)dx$  ? where $f\in L^2(A)$ (i.e. $\int_A{|f(x)|^2dx}< \infty)$ and $f$ is differentiable in $A$.

I tried to apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem and Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove this but these two theorems work on the same domain and dominated sequence of functions or monotone sequence of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: using the fact that $A$ is bounded and therefore of finite measure, show that $f \in L^2(A)$ implies $f \in L^1(A)$.  Then $|f|$ is your dominating function for the sequence $f 1_{B_n}$.